# Why does ${-}14 \bmod 12 = 10$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Why does $-14 \bmod 12 = 10$?
I would be grateful if someone could explain this to me step by step, for I am but a novice in the field of modular arithmetic. [edit] I obtained this equation by playing around with values for (x,y,z) in: x mod y = z on the Google calculator.
Thank you!

Edit: I would like to hit myself on the head- I see it now. Thanks to everyone who responded! Unless there is a discussion going on in this post right now, it can be marked as resolved.

Comment: I think it's the latter, but that wouldn't make much sense here. I was playing around with the google calculator when I came up with this equation.

Comment: @GunnarSveinsson : I would downvote your comment if I could. There is one and only one sane definition of $a \mod n$ (where $n>0$). It is the unique value in $[0,n)$ which can be obtained by adding an integral multiple of $n$ to $a$.

Comment: @MPW It is true that the first definition / notation is wrong, but it is not true that there is only one definition of *operational* mod, e.g. it might denote the canonical residue in a system of *least magnitude* reps, e.g. $\, -1,0,1\pmod{3}.\ $  Its definition is relative to the complete system of reps employed.

Comment: @MPW: Taking the latter definition gives you a function that isn't additive (i.e., $\text{mod}(a+b, n) \not= \text{mod}(a, n) + \text{mod}(b, n)$ in general, isn't multiplicative, may have strange behavior with negative arguments, and doesn't easily generalize outside the integers. It's convenient in some settings (e.g., programming) to recast $\text{mod}$ a function rather than an equivalence relation by taking a single representative of the equivalence class under it, but it's often the far less sane choice.

Comment: @MPW: ...that having been said, I'd be much happier if the definition were that $a\equiv  b\pmod{n}$ if $n| (b - a)$, rather than writing it as function-like thing "$a\, \text{mod}\, n$".

Comment: @anomaly : I think of ‘mod’ as giving the representative in the base coset

Comment: @MPW: Sure: My point was just that that representative doesn't behave well under arithmetic operations, and it doesn't generalizes to other subgroups or ideals when there isn't a canonical representative of each coset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-14\equiv10\pmod{12}\,$ because $\,{-}14=10-12\cdot 2$. In other words, $-14$ and $10$ leaves the same remainder after dividing $12.$

Comment: The notation means not only they are congruent but, further that $10$ is the *canonical* rep from the equivalence class $\,-14+12\Bbb Z\,$ wrt the complete system of residues $\bmod 12\,$ that one is using.

Answer (score 12):

14 hours before midnight, it's 10 o'clock.

Answer (score 2):

Because $10 -(-14) = 24$ which is a multiple of 12. In general, $ a\equiv b \pmod m $ means that $m$ divides $a-b$.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's tempting to think of mod as an operation, but most often in modular arithmetic, it's a modifier of $\equiv$, specifying exactly what "congruence" means. Really, if the notation had been $-14\equiv_{12}10$ instead, this would've been so much clearer.

So with this interpretation in mind, $-14\mod 12$ doesn't mean anything. On the other hand, $-14\equiv10\mod12$ is a statement. We can check whether it's true by using the definition:
$$
a\equiv b\mod c\iff c\mid a-b
$$
In this case, we get $12\mid -14-10$, which is true. This means that $-14\equiv 10\mod 12$ is true.

Comment: I disagree that $-14 \mod 12$ doesn't mean anything. I have seen this been treated as the image of $-14$ under the function $\mod 12 : \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ or even of the canonical function $ \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. In a computer science course I took this expression was treated as a number.

Comment: Although if "modular aritmetic" is more well defined than I think, you may be right that it doesnt really mean anything in that "field".

Comment: The *operation* $\bmod$ is certainly in wide use in mathematics, computer science, etc. So it is incorrect and misleading to claim the it "doesn't mean anything".

Comment: @BillDubuque I tried to make it clear that I'm talking in the context of modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Arthur And so am I.

Comment: @BillDubuque I still disagree. But I've qualified my statement the way it should've been from the start.

Comment: It is certainly your prerogative to ignore or denigrate the mod operation. but that doesn't imply that it "doesn't mean anything" to the rest of the world.

Comment: There are plenty of contexts where the operational form proves more convenient than the relational form, e.g. when performing CRT calculations using the mod Distributive Law, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2058029/242) for numbers, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050452/242) for polynomials. More generally when working in quotient structures it often proves convenient to have operationa that coerce to normal forms.

Comment: @BillDubuque You're right; having normal forms (or "distinguished representatives" or whatever one wants to call it) does make it more operator-like. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $a\text{ mod }b = c$ then there exists $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a=kb+c$. In your case, you have $a=-14$, $b=12$ and $c=10$ while $k=-2$:
$$
-14 = -2\cdot 12+10.
$$

Answer (score 1):

-24 is the largest number less than -14 which is congruent to 0 mod 12. -24 + 10 = -14 so -14 = 10 mod 12.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a positive number, you remove $12$ until you get a number between $0$ And $11$ to get the modulo.

Example: $\ 37\bmod{12}\equiv 37-12\equiv 25\equiv 25-12\equiv 13\equiv 13-12\equiv 1\pmod{12}$

For a negative number, in the same way just add $12$ until you get something positive.

Example: $\ {-}14\bmod{12}\equiv -14+12\equiv -2\equiv -2+12\equiv 10\pmod{12}$